# How to make a button show the appropriate message in Django?

Tags: django, button, django-templates

I am trying to create asocial media type site that allows users to follow other users through a Django model. For some reason, the Follow Button says "Unfollow" when a user is not following the user and says "Follow" when the user is following the other user. Do you know how to display the appropriate message? (I have tried switching the True and False values but that just makes the button say "Follow" permanently.)

views.py

```
    def username(request, user):
    #get user
    user = get_object_or_404(User.objects, username=user)
    posts = Post.objects.filter(user=user).order_by('-date_and_time')

    #follow button code
    if user == request.user:
        followButton = False
    else:
        followButton = True

    follow_or_unfollow = ''
    try:
        following = get_object_or_404(Follower, Q(
            user=user) & Q(followers=request.user))
        print(following)
    except: 
        following = False

    if following:
        follow_or_unfollow = True
    else:
        follow_or_unfollow = False

    if request.method == "POST":
        if request.POST.get('follow'):
            follower = Follower.objects.create(user=user)
            follower.followers.add(request.user)
            #Follower.objects.create(user=user, followers.set()=request.user)
            follow_or_unfollow = False
        elif request.POST.get('unfollow'):
            follower = Follower.objects.get(followers=request.user)
            follow_or_unfollow = True
            follower.remove()
       
    return render(request, "network/username.html",{
        "user": user,
        "posts": posts,
        "follow_or_unfollow": follow_or_unfollow,
        "followButton": followButton
    })
```

code in html template

```
<form action = "{% url 'username' user %}" method = "POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if follow_or_unfollow == True %}
                <input type="submit" value = "Follow" name = "follow">
            {% else %}
                <input type="submit" value = "Unfollow" name = "unfollow">
            {% endif %}
        </form>
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Follower(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="")
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="followers")
```

Comment: If `followers` is a `ManyToManyField`, I don't think you can do `Q(followers=request.user)`,

Comment: @Jarad, what should I do instead?

Comment: @Jarad, If I remove the elif about the "Unfollow" button, the model will save, so I don't know if that is the problem.

Comment: can you add your models ?

Comment: @Ayman, I added the models.

Comment: your problem is that the World doesn't change? please add the whole code of this view and explain me more about the problem

Comment: @Ayman, I am trying to save a user to the Follower model when the user presses the button when it says "Follow" and delete the user when he presses the button when it says "Unfollow." Right now, since the wrong buttons are displaying, the code is trying to delete the user from the Follower model before he is added, and I am receiving this error: ```network.models.Follower.DoesNotExist: Follower matching query does not exist.```. I am trying to display the correct button so that the other code will work.

Comment: Are you sure you need `Follower` model? Is not `User` enough?

Comment: @NixonSparrow, if I added a follower field to the User model, would I have to completely change all the other code?

Comment: @econo You would have so MUCH LESS code without `Follower` model. Especially, that you should not use `ForeignKey` but `OneToOne` relationship, if you must.

Comment: @NixonSparrow, how would I relate the follower model field to the User model if it is an object of the User model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it so much simplier without `Follower` model:

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    following = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="followers")

    def count_followers(self):
        return self.followers.all().count()
```

template.html

```
<form action = "{% url 'username' user %}" method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if user not in request.user.following.all %}
        <input type="submit" value="Follow" name="follow">
    {% else %}
        <input type="submit" value="Unfollow" name="unfollow">
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

views.py

```
def username(request, user):
    ...
    if request.method == "POST":
        if "follow" in request.POST:
            request.user.following.add(user)
        elif "unfollow" in request.POST:
            request.user.following.remove(user)
    ...
```

Comment: when I change the model, I receive this error: ```NameError: name 'User' is not defined```. Will removing the pass mess up the form that currently saves the user?

Comment: Nixon mean following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name="followers")

Comment: @econo exactly as Maxim says :)

Comment: @NixonSparrow, should ```request.user.following.add(user)``` be ```request.user.following.add(request.user)```? The user variable is the one whose profile page we are on while request.user is the visitor of the page.

Comment: No, it should be another `User` instance that current `request.user` wants to follow. If you have troubles with understanding relations in Django, I strongly suggest reading this: https://www.webforefront.com/django/setuprelationshipsdjangomodels.html or Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/

Comment: @NixonSparrow, I created a variable that displays how many followers a user has, and, whenever a user clicks the button to become a follower, the amount increases my 2. The followers for all the users are also the same even when they should not be. Is this somehow being caused when we save the follower?

Comment: @econo why variable? it's better to check followers by method that returns simply `return self.followers.all().count()`.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need user query, you can work only with post

```
<form action = "{% url 'username' post.user %}" method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if request.user != post.user %}
        {% if request.user not in post.user.followers.all %}
            <input type="submit" value = "Follow" name = "follow">
        {% else %}
            <input type="submit" value = "Unfollow" name = "unfollow">
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

dont forget add request in `context`, if you don't have a request.context_processor:

```
def username(request, user):
    ...
    return render(request, "network/username.html",{"posts": posts, "post": posts.first(), "request": request})
```

Comment: this still does not show the Unfollow button and does not delete the object.

Answer (score 0):

I like @NixonSparrow's answer very much. Along those same lines, I'll throw my answer into the mix.

**accounts/views.py**

```
import random
import string

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from accounts.models import Post
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login

def generate_fake_user():
    username = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for i in range(10))
    password = 'abc123'
    fake_user = get_user_model().objects.create(
        username=username
    )
    fake_user.set_password(password)
    fake_user.save()
    return fake_user

def username(request, user):
    # get user
    owner = get_object_or_404(get_user_model(), username=user)
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        visitor = generate_fake_user()
        login(request, visitor)
    else:
        visitor = request.user
    posts = Post.objects.filter(user=owner).order_by('-date_and_time')

    if request.method == 'POST' and request.user.is_authenticated:
        if 'follow' in request.POST:
            owner.followers.add(visitor)
        if 'unfollow' in request.POST:
            owner.followers.remove(visitor)

    context = {
        "owner"  : owner,
        "visitor": visitor,
        "posts"  : posts,
    }
    return render(request, "network/username.html", context)
```

`generate_fake_user()` is not necessary in your code. Neither is loging in the user within the view. This was necessary to create a re-usable example without a login page.

**accounts/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


class User(AbstractUser):
    followers = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name="followers")
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name="following")


class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_and_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Obviously, you probably have `Post` model somewhere else. Just here for example purposes.

**accounts/urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import username

urlpatterns = [
    path('<str:user>/', username, name='username'),
]
```

**network/username.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:50%;">

        {% for post in posts %}
        <h1>{{ post.title }}</h1>
        <div>
            <div>Owner: {{ owner }}</div>
            <div>Owner: {{ visitor }}</div>
        </div>
        <form action="{% url 'username' owner %}" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {% if visitor not in owner.followers.all %}
                <input type="submit" value="Follow" name="follow">
            {% else %}
                <input type="submit" value="Unfollow" name="unfollow">
            {% endif %}
        </form>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Before following:

[image: before following]

After following:

[image: after following]